# What happens when you use int primary id's in master master replication?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

Case: there are multiple tables all with a primary, auto increment id.
This primary id/key is a foreign key within the multiple tables to relate to each other.
This works great when there is no replication or just master - slave replication.

But what happens when you want a master - master replication?
When inserting a new record, it doesn't get for example ID of 1, but 1 on master 1, 2 on master 2 because of the offset.

If that is the case, how can one ever do relational tables/data (like MySQL is intended for) on a master master then and why is offset required? master - master should be (in my opinion) a mirror of each other.

If a customer has an ID of 2 and I query from master 1, I would get wrong data because in master 1 the customer id is 1?!

Only logical solution for me would be to create an extra column, like "customer_id".
And what if you need to update something, you would need to know the ID in master 1 and the other ID in master 2 in the where clause.

Can someone please shed some light on how this works.

Comment: The offsets ensure both servers can process an incoming write without assigning two different new records the same ID. The resulting row will replicate over to the other replicated server. The row has the same ID on both servers at the end of the process.

Comment: Ah so it used the offset to be able to insert correctly and when finished that same id is replicated to the other master. So if I insert a value, then select it (order by id desc i.e.) it returns an id for that row which is on both servers. And when updating, it just updates on one server which replicates it to the other.

But you will get gaps right. Example, if no inserts in table yet and master 2 inserts an id, master 1 will never have an id of 1?

Comment: Correct, there may be gaps - if by random chance all the inserts hit the second server, your IDs would be `2, 4, 6, 8, 10`. (The same can be true with a single server in certain situations, as well, like transactions; never assume auto-increment IDs are going to be contiguous.)

Comment: Ah yes. I don't need them to be contiguous, but I do expect ID x to be present on both servers (for relational queries) with the same data which if I understand your answer it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are missing is that the replicated insert does not use auto increment, it has the id from the master where the original insert occurred.

Note that your proposed customer_id would have the same problem.